# Man Uploads Consciousness Into Three Computers

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, computers, souls, mind-uploading

I remember reading this book a couple years ago in my school library. It was about a man who uploads his consciousness into three computers. (If I'm not mistaken) One of the uploads is the "control" with no alterations to it, one of them has no fear, and one has no emotion.

The uploads eventually break out of the closed system of their computers and escape into the internet. Then they attack his wife (Who he met in college) by hacking their home security system, and he (I think) destroys all of the uploads.

The main character then gets shot, my memory is failing me on exactly why, but he eventually goes to an afterlife where his soul is a ball of light, and he joins other souls in a giant ball of light.

Endless google attempts have gotten me no where, and Wikipedia's article on ["Mind Uploading in Fiction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading_in_fiction) doesn't seem to list the book, I've checked every entry in literature.

I apologize for the choppy description, I don't know why I didn't record the name of this book anywhere, but I really want to read it again because it was a very, very good book. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15):

The novel is [*The Terminal Experiment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminal_Experiment) by Robert J. Sawyer.  From the Amazon.com review:

> In this fast-paced thriller, Dr. Peter Hobson's investigations into death and afterlife lead him to create three separate electronic versions of himself: one has no memory of physical existence and represents life after death; one has no knowledge of death or aging and represents immortality; and the third is left unaltered as a control.